# chrome dojo mobile view

Tags: google-chrome, dojo

UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.75 Safari/537.36

Steps to reproduce the problem:
1. View the attached HTML in Chrome 62.0.3202.75
2. Notice blank page
3. Right click, View Source
4. Notice properly rendered page

What is the expected behavior?
The page should show a very simple dojo application

What went wrong?
Previous versions of Chrome properly displayed the page. The 62.0.3202 version will not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<title>Show Source to render page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js" data-dojo-config="mblUserAgent: 'WindowsPhone'"></script>
<!-- dojo configuration options -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig = {
        // Enable the AMD loader
        async: true
    };
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
    require([
        "dojox/mobile/parser",
        "dojo/domReady!",
        "dojox/mobile/View",
        "dojox/mobile/Heading"

    ], function (parser) {
        parser.parse();

    });
</script>

</head>

<body style="visibility:hidden;">
<div id="newAccount" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View">
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props="back:'Login', moveTo:'logIn'">Register </h1>
    New Account Stuff
</div>


<div id="logIn" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading" data-dojo-props="back:'Register', moveTo:'newAccount'">Log In</h1>
    Log in stuff
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dojo parser gets fired to early. The parser should wait until the DOM is loaded. I think your hitting some timing issue in the code. But if you use this code it will work:

```
require([
    "dojox/mobile/parser",
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojox/mobile/View",
    "dojox/mobile/Heading"

], function (parser,ready) {
    ready(function(){
        parser.parse();
    })


});
```

I use the dojo/ready function here to wait until the page is build in browser.